# Combine cell data, including dates and times, into one text cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to figure out how to combine many cells into one cell in a Google Sheet. The target cells contain many different types of data (date, time, text, numbers, etc.) and I need to merge them into one cell so they appear as displayed in the target cells.

I need to be able to combine the following into one cell.

```
Col A     Col B     Col C     Col D     Col E
text      date      time      text      time
```

I can use `=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1`, but it only works with text. When it gets to date or time data, it displays random numbers instead of a date or time.

Is there a method for copying the data in the cells (the way it is displayed) and merging it into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert dates or times to text **as shown**, use [`to_text`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en), e.g.,

```
= A1 & to_text(B1) & to_text(C1) & D1 & to_text(E1)
```

You can do this for every row at once:

```
=arrayformula(A1:A & to_text(B1:B) & to_text(C1:C) & D1:D & to_text(E1:E))
```

---

Within one row, one can use `join` with an appropriate delimiter like `""`, `", "` or `" "`:

```
=join(" ", arrayformula(to_text(A1:E1)))
```

(Applying `to_text` has no effect when the argument is already text.)

But this does not work for joining every row at once.

---

If you wanted dates/times to convert them in a specific format regardless of how they are displayed in the sheet, that would be done with `text`, for example `=text(B1, "m/d/yyyy")`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to set up the 1st option with an arrayformula? The data I'm combining is coming in from a Google form and I want it to auto combine as new forms are submitted. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, edited in.